# Vuln scan shows SMB1 enabled after it's been disabled

Tags: windows, server-message-block

I have two hosts, both Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard with identical initial setup. On `server1` `SMB1` has been disabled as described below, but I haven't touched `server2`.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2696547/how-to-detect-enable-and-disable-smbv1-smbv2-and-smbv3-in-windows-and

Now, the result of the vulnerability scan (`Rapid7 Nexpose`) looks like this:

```
>     +---------+------+------+--------------------+
>     | host    | prot | port | smb                |
>     +---------+------+------+--------------------+
>     | server1 | tcp  | 139  | smb1-enabled: true |
>     +---------+------+------+--------------------+
>     | server1 | tcp  | 445  | smb2-enabled: true |
>     +---------+------+------+--------------------+
>     | server2 | tcp  | 139  | smb1-enabled: true |
>     +---------+------+------+--------------------+
>     | server2 | tcp  | 445  | smb1-enabled: true |
>     |         |      |      | smb2-enabled: true |
>     +---------+------+------+--------------------+
```

I need to understand why `smb1` looks to be `enabled` on `port 139` `server1`.

Comment: What does "Get-SmbServerConfiguration | Select EnableSMB1Protocol" (powershell) return run directly on the machine? How was it disabled? Manually on the server or group policy? If manually does group policy contradict this?

Comment: This didnt work for me neither, so i googled a bit and find a solution for windows xp even though im using win 7. The solution was i that key to regedit and disable it like microsoft says then i scanned it with nmap and it showed as closed port

Comment: @Hector That PS code returns true. It was disabled on the server manually, no group policy should interfere with this setting.

Comment: Also, `Get-WindowsFeature FS-SMB1` returns that it's not installed.

Comment: This might be a better question for Nexpose support

Comment: @fishmong3r if the code returns true, then it's not disabled. It would be helpful if you would include the code you actually used to "disable" it, instead of just linking to an article.